# IntelliJ - compiler.automake.allow.app.running settings is not available in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to enable live reload for my spring project in intellj but I couldn't find the below option in the registry

compiler.automake.allow.app.running
version : IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)

I tried searching in the registry

Comment: try asking these kind of questions on intellij forum. perhaps, it can help you faster.: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users

Comment: try asking these kind of questions on intellij forum. perhaps, it can help you faster.: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the later IDEA version, this option was moved to `Settings | Advanced Settings` for easy discovery compared to the previous registry way:

[image]