# Where to find compiler.automake.allow.app.running in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Community Edition)

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

Trying to enable hot reload for my spring app project, I can't find compiler.automake.allow.app.running

Tried some tutorials but it's not in the registry tab as specified in
https://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-ide-idea/

Maybe I missed some documentation to fix this, please do let me know, thank you.

Comment: Update, I found a existing question. Already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75493999/intellij-compiler-automake-allow-app-running-settings-is-not-available-in-inte